# wkhtmltopdf.exe --no-stop-slow-scripts not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

We are using wkhtmltopdf.exe (0.10.0 rc2) to convert a very large HTML page with a lot of javascript to a PDF file. We had issues with the PDF being printed before all javascript was executed, so we decided to use the following parameters (among others) when executing wkhtmltopdf:

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe --no-stop-slow-scripts --javascript-delay 40000 <url> <pdf>
```

However, the output still gives us a warning that a slow script was stopped. When we check the PDF, certain elements that should be hidden by javascript are still visible (so I suppose that the javascript could not execute in time). When I check the HMTL page, everything looks normal and no javascript errors are shown in the console. I tried all possible combination of the above two parameters, without any result.

```
>wkhtmltopdf.exe --no-stop-slow-scripts --javascript-delay 40000 
--print-media-type --no-outline --title "My title" --footer-center "My footer"
--footer-font-name "Verdana" --footer-font-size 4 --no-footer-line 
--cookie MyCookie MyCookieKey=MyCookieValue 
"http://..." "C:\Users\...\Documents\TestPDF.pdf"

Loading pages (1/6)
Warning: A slow script was stopped      <<< Why does it still show this warning?
Counting pages (2/6)
Resolving links (4/6)
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
```

So why would wkhtmltopdf ignore these parameters?
Could it have anything to do with the version of wkhtmltopdf? Or could it be caused by the use of jQuery in these HTML page?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: FYI, I don't think you "need" (or maybe even "can use") both `--no-stop-slow-scripts` and `--javascript-delay 40000`. By setting `--no-stop-slow-scripts`, I _believe_ you're essentially setting an javascript delay of infinity. That was my experience but not 100% sure.

Comment: FYI, `--no-stop-slow-scripts` works just fine, at least on 0.12.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this issue was updating to the most recent version (0.12.3.2). With this version, we don't even need the `--javascript-delay` or `--no-stop-slow-scripts` anymore...